# program works but when I debug it says "<error reading characters in string.>" in line when reading file line by line

Tags: c, string, pointers, file-io

I wrote this code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *actionfpnt;
    char* line[70];
    actionfpnt = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (actionfpnt == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: opening %s failed\n", "actions");
    }
    else
    {
        while (fgets(line, 70, actionfpnt) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", line);
        }
        fclose(actionfpnt);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

while argv[1] is an address to a txt file, and in this text file:

```
Initialize
Fatal_malfunction $$$ cpu Zi7 $$$ 130
Fatal_malfunction $$$ cpu Zi5 $$$ 15
Returned_from_customer $$$ cpu Zi7 $$$ 10
Rename $$$ bloblo12zZzZ $$$ Zbloblo
Returned_from_customer $$$ Zblabla $$$ 10
Finalize
```

the confusing part is that the code actually working but when I try to debug it, I see in the variable "line" : `"<error reading characters in string.>"`.
the output is:

```
Initialize

Fatal_malfunction $$$ cpu Zi7 $$$ 130

Fatal_malfunction $$$ cpu Zi5 $$$ 15

Returned_from_customer $$$ cpu Zi7 $$$ 10

Rename $$$ bloblo12zZzZ $$$ Zbloblo

Returned_from_customer $$$ Zblabla $$$ 10

Finalize
```

when I try to execute anything else with line, I cant because "line" doesnt really contain anything.
I would really appreciate a way to solve this issue, and an explenation to why the code worked and got the right output even with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You want `char line[70];` not `char* line[70];`!

`char* line[70];` is an array of 70 pointers to `char`.

---

As `fgets()` includes reading the line's end you want to `printf` without an additional terminating `\n`:

```
  printf("%s", line);
```

And though as no formatting is required using `fputs()` would be sufficient:

```
  fputs(line, stdout);
```